# Make quick shop direct to product

Tags: php, template

On the category page I have a quick shop "Add to Cart" button, which adds one type of the product to the cart for virtual and simple products.
Instead I would like this button to simply make it open the product.
Below is my code;

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if ( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product)
    || $_product->isGrouped()) ): ?>

    <button rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" type="button" 
    title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn-cart lort" 
    onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if ( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product)
    || $_product->isGrouped()) ): ?>

    <button rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" type="button" 
    title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn-cart lort" 
    onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getUrlInStore() ?>')">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```